# Three equal divs in a row, with image and border

Tags: html, css, width, border

I currently have a section of a page with three divs that house images and act as links. I have them perfectly in a row now by using 33% in the css for width, but I have an issue.

I need these images to be slightly smaller than the div and have black borders between them, like this:

[image]

I added a black border to the right of the first two line items but it knocks the last element down to the next row. This row does need to be 100% width, but I need some help getting these guys to fit equally yet still have space between with a border.

Code:

```html
<div id="imageLinkRow" style="letter-spacing: 2px; font-weight:500;  width:100%;">
<ul style="font-weight:500;">
    <div class="firstItem">
        <li style="width:33%; text-align:center; float:left; \">
        <div><a href="#"><img src="https://dev.dutil.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/film.jpg" " /></a></div>
        <div style="text-align:center;">WHAT'S NEW</div></li>
    </div>

    <div class="secondItem">
    <li  style="width:33%;  text-align: center; float:left; ">
    <div><a href="#"><img src="https://dev.dutil.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/officeGroup.jpg" "  /></a></div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">ADVERTISING</div></li>
    </div>

    <div class="thirdItem">
    <li  style="width:33%; float:left; ">
    <div><a href="#"><img src="https://dev.dutil.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/bobble.jpg"   /></a></div>
    <div style="color:white;">&NBSP</div>
    </li>
    </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please correct the (multiple) syntax errors, you have surplus `"` characters and `&nbsp` should be `&nbsp;` (with the semi-colon), although you can still use the upper-case format if you really want to. Also a `<div>` is *not* a valid child of the `<ul>` element; the *only* valid child of a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`) is an `<li>`; if you want a `<div>` within the `<ul>` then it must first be wrapped in an `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different options to achieve this.

The easiest is probably setting

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

This will tell the browser, that it has to consider the border, when it calculates the width. Thus, 33% width is technically 33% - 1px content width.

Other alternatives are the use of `width:calc()` or a flex-box or grid layout.

Also, you have quite a lot of errors in your html. You probably should use a validator like https://validator.w3.org/ to check your code.

```css
div{
box-sizing:border-box;
width:33%;
display:inline-block;
border-right:2px solid black;
text-align:center;
}
#one{
  background:rgba(255,0,0,.2);
}
#two{
  background:rgba(0,255,0,.2);
}
#three{
  background:rgba(0,0,255,.2);
  border:none;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"><img src="https://dev.dutil.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/film.jpg" /></div><div id="two"><img src="https://dev.dutil.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/officeGroup.jpg"  /></div><div id="three"><img src="https://dev.dutil.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/bobble.jpg"/></div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! Just to be clear, I would set each of my three divs with the border-box, but not my parent div? In other words, your div code would be in the CSS for all three of my div classes (firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem)?

Comment: @Hunter Yes, it goes on the container divs, where you specify the border. However, it does not hurt on the parent div as well - whatever you prefer. Also you should correct the errors in your html code, I post a link in the answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! So for responsiveness, I can just set the media screens to remove the two borders and make each one 100% width?

Comment: That's exactly what you would do! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding a border to your element, the width will grown to 33% + the width of the border.

Try

```
.firstItem.li 
{ 
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 2px); 
}
```

2px is the width of the border.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Equi-distant divs" CSS trick. This makes your div distribute themselves equally across the horizontal axis. This trick is very easy to apply and will save you a lot of time.

https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/